# splice function doesn't work on array of integer as expected?

Tags: arrays, integer, array-splice

I was trying to use the splice() function to manipulate an array of integers. But all I am getting is strange results.

Here is my code

```js
var g = [0,1];
//Expected result [0, 1, 1]
//Actual result [0]
console.log(g.splice(0, 1, 0, 1));
//Expected result [0,5]
//Actual result [1]
console.log(g.splice(1, 1, 5));
```

Can any of you help me understand the usage of splice on integer array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [No "_thanks"_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What didn't you find about `splice` function in Javascript documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_splice.htm) that should help.  Basically the first element is index to insert the next param is how many elements to remove the next arguments are the elements to add to the array.

Description
Javascript array splice() method changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.

Syntax
Its syntax is as follows −

`array.splice(index, howMany, [element1][, ..., elementN]);`
Parameter Details
index − Index at which to start changing the array.

howMany − An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If howMany is 0, no elements are removed.

element1, ..., elementN − The elements to add to the array. If you don't specify any elements, splice simply removes the elements from the array.

Return Value
Returns the extracted array based on the passed parameters.

Comment: Link-only answers are bad. Imagine the link is broken, no one can understand what you're talking about. Hence link-only.

Comment: @jonathan Have you test the code yourself? I read the documentation on [mozilla developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). I want to know if this work for an array of integer? Thank you for everyone's help.